# Block an asp:Button OnClick event in C# from the OnClientClick event in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick, onclientclick

I have an `asp:Button` on my webpage, and it calls into a JavaScript function and a code-behind method. The latter makes a call to navigate to another page. In the JavaScript function, I'm checking for a condition. If this condition is not met, I want to abort the navigation so that the `OnClick` method is not called. Is this possible?

```
<asp:Button OnClick="Button_Click" ID="Action1" OnClientClick="SaveValues()"
    Text="Action1" CssClass="specialButton" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To block `OnClick` from executing, just return `false` from `OnClientClick`:

```
<asp:Button OnClick="Button_Click" ID="Action1" OnClientClick="return SaveValues();"
    Text="Action1" CssClass="specialButton" runat="server" />
```

Assuming that `SaveValues` will also return a boolean whether or not the condition was met.

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks. marking as answer because of source and time.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible

```
function SaveValues()
{
if(//check your codition here)
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}

<asp:Button OnClick="Button_Click" ID="Action1" OnClientClick="javascript:return SaveValues();" Text="Action1" CssClass="specialButton" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning `true` or `false`, according to the success of the JavaScript, should prevent or enable the button to submit. So, instead of just tacking it on at the end of `OnClientClick`, where you'd have to conditionalise it and immediately make your call look much more ugly, let the method indicate its operational status.